# ヒストグラムの縦軸の数が小数になる

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

下記のようなコードを書きました。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'value': [
            5000, 4000, 2500, 1100, 1000, 900, 800,
            453,392,380,296,207,160,130,100,41,40,32,31,26,25,15,10,9,7
        ]
    }
)

sns.histplot(df["value"], kde=False)
```

結果は下記の通りです

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

500までのCountが17.5個となっているように思います。
500までの数は,`453,392,380,296,207,160,130,100,41,40,32,31,26,25,15,10,9,7` で、全部で18個のはずです。どうして17.5個なのでしょうか？　もしくは目盛りが読みにくいだけで、微妙にずれているので、18を指しているのでしょうか？ もし18個で正しいのであれば、縦軸に小数点は今回不要なので、整数のみにしたいです。

参考: [ヒストグラムとは？ヒストグラムの書き方(作り方)や分布図の見方を徹底解説](https://backlog.com/ja/blog/what-is-a-histogram/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実際には `18` になっています。

```py
            :
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
            :

ax = sns.histplot(df["value"], kde=False)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(3))
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]